# Safari isn't reading my responsive CSS on my wordpress website

Tags: css, wordpress, responsive-design, mobile-safari

For some reason, Safari for iPhone isn't reading the responsive CSS, something must be stopping the it...but I can't find a bug or error. I've been through the CSS with a fine tooth comb and checked.

The live development site is at: http://k16.koogardevelopment.co.uk/

Comment: How are you trying to build a responsive website? - `Flexbox` or `Media Query` or something else

Comment: #tweets is broken also when the navbar is inactive state.

Comment: Yes, Andrew I am. It's responsive in everything but mobile Safari. I am using media queries for that.

Thanks, Herm. I'll look at that.

Comment: Could you provide a simple sample with JSFiddle?

Comment: here's the JSFiddle css, hopefully I've done it right; https://jsfiddle.net/uorg6eqL/

Answer (score 0):

The root of your problem is that some of your divs have hard coded widths that aren't scaling down or reseting for narrow viewports. For example you have

```
body{
 min-width:960px;
}
```

The divs I noticed that need attention are body, #main, #tweets ul, and #branding

Two of your options are to either change the width settings for these elements to something that will scale, e.g. `{ width:100%;}` or use media queries so you can target and change them at specific viewports, e.g.

```
@media screen and (max-width: 767px) {    /*adjust width as required  */
  #element-you-want-to-target{
    width: Xpx;
  }

}
```

Good luck!